# Por que no se visualiza el selected seleccionado? SELECT2

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Soy nuevo en la plataforma y requiero ayuda de los mas grandes.
Tengo una librería en uso que es SELECT2.

El problema es:
-Cuando le doy un click a mi tabla, a una fila en especifico, obtengo los datos de esa fila en un array con JQUERY, luego los cargo con val() al id del select que quiero seleccionar.

Resultado:
-Antes de poner en uso la libreria, esto funciona correctamente, el selected funciona y se ve el elemnto seleccionado en el select de mi formulario, pero cuando pongo la clase de la libreria... esta se activa, y el elemento selected no se visualiza directamente en el formulario, se ve seleccionado unicamente cuando le doy click al select, no sin antes seleccionarlo.

Espero que puedan ayudarmen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen de arriba ya seleccioné al usuario que por nombre lleva Admin web, si se dan cuenta el select de la parte de abajo dice aun Seleccione, no cambia su estado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando le doy click al select si está seleccionado el elemento que debe señalar.
Lo que quiero lograr con esto es que el elemento que yo cargue al select se visualice y no que me muestre simplemente un Seleccione.

Gracias por su atención a todos.

Anexo imagenes del JS con el cual creo el objeto de la libreria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que utilizo para cargar los elementos del HTML con JQUERY

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. parece te hace falta invocar `.trigger('change')` del mismo elemento que invocas el `val` (https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items)

Comment: Muchas gracias, su solución fue de utilidad y funciona correctamente, buen día.